# Saving log files to pc in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, save

Is it possible to write log files to my pc?
I'm creating a log file inside my android app which i need to analyze on my pc, is it possible to save this file directly to my pc? The app runs on my tablet which is connected via USB.

Comment: you can write your logs into logcat (simultaneously) and see them on pc and even copy them.

Comment: This would be a really nice feature. For all files, not just logs.

Answer (score 0):

//to read the logcat programmatically

```
try {
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
         log.append(line);
       }      
} 
catch (IOException e) {
}

//to create a Text file name "logcat.txt" in SDCard
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");
```